# Ajax send multiple base64 image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image, base64

I'm sending multiple images through ajax request. But there is a problem with sending more than one image, because of it's memory.

When i try to json_decode this object **thumbnailArray**. I got this

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 1048655 bytes)

```
thumbnailArray = {
    image1 : {
        image : base64,
        rotate : 0,
        order : 1
    },
    image2 : {
        image : base64,
        rotate : 0,
        order : 2
    }
}
```

I'm sending base64 image in object with some values like image rotation and order. 
This is code :

```
    var formData = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
    formData.append('ab-user-image', JSON.stringify(thumbnailArray));

    $.ajax({
        url : baseUrl+'user/ajax_user_add/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        async : true,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function(data) {
            //success
        }
    });
```

Is there better way to send base64 images or to improve this code or something?

Comment: What's `thumbnailArray`? Your code snippet is useful, but without knowing what you are trying to serialize and why is it so big, you won't get much help.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer I said that is object. Never mind, i update post, and add thumbnailArray, you can see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with this

```
var picReader = new FileReader();
picReader.onload = function(event){
    $('.ab-image-upload .ab-image-uploaded').append(createContainerThumbnail(event.target.result, j));
    thumbnailArray['ab-user-image'+j] = {
         image: event.target.result,
         rotate: 0,
         order: 0
    };
    j++;
};
picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
if(formData) {
    formData.append('images[]', file);
}
```

I append in **formData** files direct in **FileReader**. And than send via ajax

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the limits in your php.ini:

upload_max_filesize
post_max_size

or repcreate the ajax function to make 1 call for each image

You can recreate the ajax function with something like this:

```
var formData

 = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
    formData.append('ab-user-image', JSON.stringify(thumbnailArray));

    $(formData).each().ajax({
        url : baseUrl+'user/ajax_user_add/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : this,
        async : true,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function(data) {
            //success
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I can't change php.ini file.
I'm doing multiple file upload, on submit, i need to send all images to php, than uploaded it etc.. and save in database. If you have solution for this. this will be great

Comment: I try this and if i have image bigger than 10-15MB it's same, is there another way to send images with ajax?

Comment: You need acces to your php.ini or you have your hands tied

Comment: I'm on shared server, i can't change php.ini :/

Comment: Then you can't do your web as you want it :/

Comment: Is there another solution? 
I have input multiple file. And when add some images, automatically show it on page. I do that with filereader (and create base64 images)

Comment: You could break the file into pieces that you can upload, upload it, and then reattach the pieces using php... way more complicated

Comment: I did it, you can see answer, but thank you, you helped me a lot!